# Coloring in boxes

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array, colors

I'm trying to create a 2D array of colored boxes, but all I'm getting are decimal numbers in each box.

```
let adjustSize = document.getElementById("dimension");
adjustSize.addEventListener("change", function () {
  let size = parseInt(adjustSize.value);
  // fullTable.innerHTML = "";
  var array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      array[i][j] = Math.random();
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        array[i][j].className = document.getElementsByClassName("popXColor");
      } else {
        array[i][j].className = document.getElementsByClassName("popYColor");
      }
    }
  }
  drawTable(array);
});
function drawTable(array) {
  let t = document.createElement("table");
  let div = document.querySelector("#board");
  div.appendChild(t);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = array[i][j];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    t.appendChild(tr);
  }
  return t;
}
```

I've tried to utilize the following HTML attributes for the boxes:

```
        <tr>
          <td class="field"><label for="popXcolor">Population 1:</label></td>
          <td class="field">
            <input id="popXcolor" type="color" value="#006EFF" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="field"><label for="popYcolor">Population 2:</label></td>
          <td class="field">
            <input id="popYcolor" type="color" value="#FF7B00" />
          </td>
        </tr>
```

If you know a solution, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want something like this, correct?

[image: Color grid]

If so, you're not too far off from what you're trying to achieve. The first section that needed adjustment was where you're storing the value of the color of `#popXcolor` or `#popYcolor` into the array. If you're randomly selecting one color or the other, adding the value of the color input will work fine for this step.

```js
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  array[i][j] = document.getElementById("popXcolor").value;
} else {
  array[i][j] = document.getElementById("popYcolor").value;
}
```

Once you have that in place, you just have to add the color to the appropriate styles (I used `backgroundColor` in my example, see [styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) for more details):

```js
td.style.backgroundColor = array[i][j];
```

In my full example, I made some changes to help me understand and answer your question.

### Set references at the start

- I wanted to be able to use the `#board`, `#popXcolor`, and `#popYcolor` elements without calling the DOM in functions and loops, so I created references to each at the beginning of my code.
- To reduce additional DOM calls, I created empty `table`, `tr`, and `td` elements at the start and call [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) in the `drawTable` function.

### Extracted function

- I extracted the implementation details of the event listener for `change` on the `adjustSize` element and placed it into a function, called `changeSquares`.
- I wanted to be able to call the function on code run/load, so creating a dedicated function for this made this very easy to implement.

### Variable declaration changes

- I changed the `size` variable to `length` to be able to easily use it in the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method.
- I modified the name of `array` for clarity to `arrayOfColors`.
- Since I am creating the array using `Array.from()`, I can create the colors in the `mapFn` value initiator, so the `for` loops were removed.
- Using the [`Conditional (ternary) operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it allowed me to reduce the code further down and remove the `if..else` blocks as well.
- Most of the `var` variable declarations were changed to `let` if the value needed to be changed and `const` otherwise.

```js
const adjustSize = document.getElementById("dimension");
const board = document.getElementById("board");
const popXcolor = document.getElementById("popXcolor");
const popYcolor = document.getElementById("popYcolor");
const tableElement = document.createElement("table");
const tableRowElement = document.createElement("tr");
const tableCellElement = document.createElement("td");

const drawTable = (array) => {
  board.innerHTML = "";
  const t = tableElement.cloneNode();
  board.appendChild(t);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const tr = tableRowElement.cloneNode();
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      const td = tableCellElement.cloneNode();
      td.style.backgroundColor = array[i][j];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    t.appendChild(tr);
  }
};

const changeSquares = () => {
  const length = parseInt(adjustSize.value);
  const arrayOfColors = Array.from({
    length
  }, () => {
    return Array.from({
      length
    }, () => {
      return Math.random() < 0.5 ? popXcolor.value : popYcolor.value;
    });
  });
  drawTable(arrayOfColors);
};

adjustSize.addEventListener("change", changeSquares);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeSquares);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

#board td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div><label for="dimension">Number of rows and columns</label></div>
<div><input id="dimension" type="number" min="1" step="1" value="3" /></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><label for="popXcolor">Population 1:</label></td>
    <td class="field">
      <input id="popXcolor" type="color" value="#006EFF" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><label for="popYcolor">Population 2:</label></td>
    <td class="field">
      <input id="popYcolor" type="color" value="#FF7B00" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="board"></div>
```